# combine two image maps

Tags: html, imagemap

How I can combine two image maps?

I have the following areas ...

```
<area shape="poly"  a coords="260,143, 265,143, 265,142, 266,142, 266,143, 267,143, 267,144, 276,144, 277,144, 277,145, 280,145, 280,146, 286,146, 286,147, 287,147, 287,156, 288,156, 288,157, 290,157, 290,159, 291,159, 291,168, 290,168, 290,176, 288,176, 288,177, 287,177, 287,181, 286,181, 286,182,
280,182, 280,183,
279,183, 279,184, 277,184, 277,185, 275,185, 275,186, 272,186, 272,189, 269,189, 269,188, 265,188, 265,187, 262,187, 262,186, 261,186, 261,185, 260,185, 260,184, 258,184, 258,183, 257,183, 257,182, 256,182, 256,181, 255,181, 255,180, 253,180, 253,178, 251,178, 251,175, 250,175, 250,173, 249,173, 249,171, 248,171, 248,170,
247,170, 247,163, 248,163, 248,161, 249,161, 249,159, 251,159, 251,158, 252,158, 252,157, 253,157, 253,156, 254,156, 254,155, 256,155, 256,154, 257,154, 257,153, 258,153, 258,152, 259,152, 259,151, 260,151" href="#" />


<area shape="poly" a coords="286,142, 286,144, 287,144, 288,144, 288,143, 289,143, 289,141, 287,141, 287,142" href="#" />
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. The areas don't overlap.

Otherwise you could find the segments of the polygons that intersect and
recreate new lines that surround the bigger combined polygon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it could not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can draw a single pixel line connecting the two areas you can pull it off.  Then it'll just be one map.

its tricky, but can be done.